# Showing bestseller of each category in navigation in Magento 1.7

Tags: php, navigation, magento-1.7

I'm looking for a possibility to get the most sold product by category to show it in a specific part of the navigation. To show the product(s) isn't the problem but getting them.

I already did a intensive search through Google with different keywords but all I got were outdated plugins, modifications for bestseller.phtml (which doesn't exit in Magento 1.7 anymore) and setting filters on the resource model but I haven't found anymore which got me any result.

So I tried to get the products by myself (so far, it just should get the sales of any product, not the best one):

```
$category->getId();
    $children = $category->getChildren();

    foreach($children as $child)
    {
        $childCategoryIdString = $child->getId();
        $childCategoryId = substr($childCategoryIdString, 14);

        $childCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
            ->load($childCategoryId);

        $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addCategoryFilter($childCategory)
            ->load();

        $allIds = $productCollection->getAllIds();

        for($i = 0; $i < count($allIds); $i++)
        {
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($allIds[$i]);
            echo $product->getOrderedQty() . '_';
        }
    }
```

This has two issues: First it's making Magento yet slower. Second `$product->getOrderedQty()`, a method I have found in various results of my search, doesn't work. Now I don't really know what else I could try and looking for some help which is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're using a lot of objects wrappers in your sample script. Methods like `load` encapsulated into multiple loops will produce huge delays and possibly huge memory usage (base on your product collection size).

When I addressed this issue the other day I decided to use straight ORM methods instead of objects for better performance.

There are two possible ways to show bestsellers. The less resources-consuming is to use aggregated bestsellers tables (like `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily`), but it has huge drawback - the data inside those tables is not updating authomatically. It's used in Admin Reports section, and will be updates only when you choose to refresh your statistics.

The other but much more reliable method is to join `sales_flat_order_item` table to retrieve sales_qty for each product. Obviously it's more resource consuming, since you have to count it yourself.

In my script I've chosen the latter path. I've modified it to meet your logic requirements. Also I've added a couple of `joins` to get Category name, you might not need that. But enough talking :) here's the code of my `test.php` shell script:

```
<?php
require_once 'abstract.php';

/**
 * Magento Test Bestsellers script
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Shell
 */
class Mage_Shell_Test extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Run script
     *
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // benchmarking
        $memory = memory_get_usage();
        $time = microtime();
        echo "Starting mem usage: $memory\n";

        $catId = $this->getArg('category');
        /** @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        // join sales order items column and count sold products
        $expression = new Zend_Db_Expr("SUM(oi.qty_ordered)");
        $condition = new Zend_Db_Expr("e.entity_id = oi.product_id AND oi.parent_item_id IS NULL");
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name')->getSelect()
            ->join(array('oi' => $collection->getTable('sales/order_item')),
            $condition,
            array('sales_count' => $expression))
            ->group('e.entity_id')
            ->order('sales_count' . ' ' . 'desc');
        // join category
        $condition = new Zend_Db_Expr("e.entity_id = ccp.product_id");
        $condition2 = new Zend_Db_Expr("c.entity_id = ccp.category_id");
        $collection->getSelect()->join(array('ccp' => $collection->getTable('catalog/category_product')),
            $condition,
            array())->join(array('c' => $collection->getTable('catalog/category')),
            $condition2,
            array('cat_id' => 'c.entity_id'));
        $condition = new Zend_Db_Expr("c.entity_id = cv.entity_id AND ea.attribute_id = cv.attribute_id");
        // cutting corners here by hardcoding 3 as Category Entiry_type_id
        $condition2 = new Zend_Db_Expr("ea.entity_type_id = 3 AND ea.attribute_code = 'name'");
        $collection->getSelect()->join(array('ea' => $collection->getTable('eav/attribute')),
            $condition2,
            array())->join(array('cv' => $collection->getTable('catalog/category') . '_varchar'),
            $condition,
            array('cat_name' => 'cv.value'));
        // if Category filter is on
        if ($catId) {
            $collection->getSelect()->where('c.entity_id = ?', $catId)->limit(1);
        }

        // unfortunately I cound not come up with the sql query that could grab only 1 bestseller for each category
        // so all sorting work lays on php
        $result = array();
        foreach ($collection as $product) {
            /** @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
            if (isset($result[$product->getCatId()])) {
                continue;
            }
            $result[$product->getCatId()] = 'Category:' . $product->getCatName() . '; Product:' . $product->getName() . '; Sold Times:'. $product->getSalesCount();
        }

        print_r($result);

        // benchmarking
        $memory2 = memory_get_usage();
        $time2 = microtime();
        $memDiff = ($memory2 - $memory)/1000000;
        $timeDiff = $time2 - $time;
        echo 'Time spent:' . $timeDiff . "s\n";
        echo "Ending mem usage: $memory2\n";
        echo "Mem used : {$memDiff}M\n";
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Usage Help Message
     *
     */
    public function usageHelp()
    {
        return <<<USAGE
Usage:  php -f test.php -- [options]
        php -f test.php -- --category 1

  --categories <category> Filter by Category, if not specified, all categories are outputted
  help                      This help

USAGE;
    }
}

$shell = new Mage_Shell_Test();
$shell->run();
```

To use it just create a file `test.php` in your *shell* folder and insert the code I've provided into the file. See `usageHelp` if you're not familiar with command line php calls.

P.S. Added some benchmarking there to track your mem_usage and time.

**UPDATE** Upon reviewing the issue further I've found more elegant way to get the Bestsellers for each category using only `Zend_Db` adapter. The result will contain only `category_id` => `product_id` connection (not Magento Objects), but it's much easier and overall better. This code should go between the *benchmarking* blocks into the `run` function:

```
    $catId = $this->getArg('category');

    /** @var $resource Mage_Core_Model_Resource */
    $resource = Mage::getModel('core/resource');
    /** @var $adapter Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract */
    $adapter = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

    $select = $adapter->select()
        ->from(array('c' => $resource->getTableName('catalog/category')), array('cat_id'=>'entity_id'))
        ->join(array('ccp' => $resource->getTableName('catalog/category_product')), 'c.entity_id = ccp.category_id', array())
        ->join(array('oi' => $resource->getTableName('sales/order_item')), 'ccp.product_id = oi.product_id', array('max_qty' => new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(oi.qty_ordered - oi.qty_canceled)'), 'product_id' => 'product_id'))
        ->where('oi.parent_item_id is null')
        ->group('c.entity_id')
        ->group('oi.product_id')
        ->order('entity_id ASC')
        ->order('max_qty DESC');
    if ($catId) {
        $select->where('c.entity_id = ?', $catId);
    }
    $res = $adapter->fetchAll($select);

    $result = array();
    foreach ($res as $oneRes) {
        if (isset($result[$oneRes['cat_id']])) {
            continue;
        }
        $result[$oneRes['cat_id']] = $oneRes;
    }

    array_walk($result, function($var, $key) {
        echo 'Category Id:' . $key . ' | Product Id:' . $var['product_id'] . ' | Sales Count:' . $var['max_qty'] . "\n";
    });
```

Comment: Sorry for my late reply but thank you for your informative answer! Running your script returns four empty arrays. As there are no sold products so far I'm not surprised that they are completely empty (well, shouldn't at least the text strings within?) but that I got four. I have four parent categories but defined $catId as "17" (one of my child categories ID) for testing purposes. Have I overseen something?

Comment: Just a note on this, those sales_bestsellers_aggregated get populated by a cron job in magneto's cron scheduler system

Answer (score 0):

```
$visibility = array(
                      Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                      Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
                  );
$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->load(2); //My cat id is 10
$prodCollection = $category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $visibility)->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');
<?php foreach($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
//whatever you want
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately the snippet does strange things as it outputs four times the same two products (this says at least echo $_product->getId()) - and the category I had loaded has six items. So I expect them or no one (as no product has been sold so far).